# Good information on adding user login (session) to my website

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication

I've never had any kind of user authentication on my site before. However, I've now created (or am in the process of creating) a website which depends on it. I've read that there is cookies vs sessions and the general consensus is that sessions is more secure -- so I'm thinking of going that way.

Seeing as I'm completely lost as to how to make this work, I'm looking for a great beginner's guide to setting it up securely. By this I mean a step-by-step for me to get it up and running on my site.

Comment: I've google and only come up with poorly written tutorials for non-noobs on the subject. Plus there's no way for me to validate what they're saying. Here, I can be sure that intelligent people stir me on the right path :)

Comment: Sessions and cookies are used for maintaining state, not for authentication at login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions are more secure in the sense that only a token is stored on the client side, not the data itself like with a cookie. Therefore, cookies can easily be manipulated and should only be trusted in the same way that you trust `POST` or `GET` data. You can, however, do the same thing with a cookie manually.

What I usually do is to store a random token that corresponds to a database entry in a cookie.

For instance, when a user logs in, a random token is generated. This token is inserted into the database along with the user's ID and what other information you wish to store with the cookie. Then, the only thing stored in the cookie itself, is the random token.

When you wish to access the cookie, you just look up the token in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Well basicaly you store all your sensitive data in a PHP [session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) (like the fact that the user is actually logged in, or that he has some special privileges), and sotre the session identifier in a cookie. But this is often handled automatically by PHP itself.

So you just have to authentificate the user, store information about him in a session, and show a success message.

The next time your user is going to visit your page, you just have to check whether or not he already has a session. To log him out, you just destroy his session.

Sessions are really simple to use. They are said to be more secure because the user can not access his session data, while he can modify his own cookies.